# Lectura de datos tipo NodoL

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

¿Qué tipo de identificador de variable se usa para leer una variable de tipo nodo?

Tira el siguiente error

> warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int *', but argument 2 has type 'nodoL * {aka struct nodo *}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig;
} nodoL;

int main(void) {
    nodoL n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%x\n", n.info);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Qué tipo de identificador de variables se usa para leer una variable de tipo nodo?

No hay identificador para ese tipo y la razón es que es un tipo definido por el usuario.

`scanf` solo está habilitado para almacenar valores en los tipos nativos, que son los que conoce el estándar del lenguaje: `int`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `char*` (para cadenas), ...

Los tipos definidos por el usuario al final acaban usando tipos nativos por debajo. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear funciones que modifiquen esas variables. Las estructuras no son más que un mecanismo que permite agrupar y organizar tipos nativos para mejorar la legibilidad y claridad del código.

**EDITO**

Pregunta realizada via comentario:

> ¿Y cómo se lee una variable tipo nodo?

La variable de tipo `nodo` no se lee... lo que hay que hacer es rellenar las variables nativas que tiene dentro:

```
scanf("%d", &n.info);
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo se lee una variable tipo nodo?

Comment: @AlejandroCaro he editado la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

Programa funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig;
} nodoL;

int main(void) {
    nodoL n;
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    printf("%x\n", n.info);

    return 0;
}
```