# Tabla Hash en C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, hash

Tengo este programa que debería implementar una función hash en C++. El programa compila pero presenta errores en tiempo de ejecución

Aquí el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#define HASHMAX 10

using namespace std;

typedef struct nodoL
{
    int info;
    nodoL * sig;
    nodoL * ant;
} nodo;

typedef nodo* lista;

// DEFINICIÓN DE LAS FUNCIONES
//************* HASH **********

typedef lista Hash[HASHMAX];
int HashClave(int n);
void HashInsertar(Hash &h, int e);
void HashMostrar(Hash h);
void HashBuscar(Hash h, int n);

//********  LISTA   *******
void enlistar (lista &L, int n);
int mostrar(lista L);/* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista &L, int n);

int HashClave (int n)
{
    return n%HASHMAX;
}

void HashInsertar (Hash &h, int e)
{
    enlistar ((h)[HashClave(e)],e);
}

void enlistar (lista &L, int n)
{
    lista aux = new nodoL;
    if(L==NULL)
    {
        aux -> info = n;
        aux -> sig = L;
        L=aux;
    }
    else
    {
        if((L)->info>n) // Para que quede ordenado
        {
            aux -> info = n;
            aux -> sig = L;
            L=aux;
        }
        else
        {
            enlistar(L->sig,n); //<-- warning: passing argument 1 of 'enlistar' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
        }
    }
}

int mostrar (lista L)
{
    int i=0;
    if(L!=NULL)
    {
        i=1;
        cout << "[" << L->info << "]->";
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    return i;
}

void HashMostrar(Hash h)
{
    int i, n;
    for (n=0; n<HASHMAX; n++)
    {
        cout << "Hash ["<<n<<"]: ";
        i=mostrar(h[n]);
        if(i==0)cout << "Lista  vacia " <<endl << endl;
        else cout << "#" << endl << endl;
    }
}

void borrar(lista *L, int n)
{
    lista aux = *L; //puntero auxiliar al primer nodo
    lista ant = NULL;
    if(aux==NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: Lista vacia";
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux->info!=n&&aux->sig!=NULL)
        {
            ant=aux;
            aux=aux->sig;
        }
        if(aux->sig==NULL&&aux->info!=n)
               cout << "Error, numero no se encuentra en la lista";
        else
        {
            ant->sig=aux->sig;
            delete aux;   //elimino el nodo de la memoria
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Se declara y asigna una la variable para controlar la opción seleccionada en el menú.
    int op=-1;
    int i;
    //Se declara una variable milista de tipo lista.
    lista milista=NULL;
    //Se declara una variable h de tipo Hash
    Hash h;
    //Mientras op se distinto de 0 (Cuando es op=0 finaliza el programa.)
    while(op)
    {
        system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
        //Mostrar en pantalla las opciones del menú.
        cout << "\t\tEjemplo de Hash" << endl <<endl << "\tSeleccione una opcion" << endl <<endl <<"\t-1. Agregar elemento a la lista" <<endl << "\t-2. Mostrar lista" << endl << "\t-3. Borrar un elemento" << endl << "\t-0. Salir" <<endl;
        cin >> op; //Captura el numero opción seleccionada.
        switch(op) //Ir a la opción indicada por el usuario.
        {
            //Ingresar un valor al comienzo de la lista.
        case 1:
        {
            int e, n;//Crear una variable para el número a insertar en la lista llamada e y otra para la clave del hash llamada n
            system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
            cout << "Ingrese la clave del hash para el elemento:" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            cout << "Ingrese el numero para agregar a la lista, 0 para terminar:" << endl;//Pedir por pantalla un número para insertar en la lista.
            do{
                cin >> e;//Capturar el número a insertar en la lista.
                HashInsertar(h,e);//<-------LLamará al procedimiento que inserta un numero al hash.
                cout << e << " se ha agregado con exito a la lista" << endl;
            }while (e != 0);
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        //Mostrar lista por pantalla.
        case 2:
        {
            system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
            //Mostrar en pantalla un titulo.
            cout << "Los numeros cargados en la lista:" << endl << endl;
            //Declarar un variable y asignarle el valor devuelto por la función mostrar (0 Lista vacía 1 Lista no vacía).
            i = mostrar(milista);
            //Chequear si la lista esta vacía y mostrar en pantalla el exto que corresponda.
            if(i==0)
                cout << "La lista esta vacia" <<endl <<endl;
            else
                cout << "# "<<endl <<endl;
            //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
        //Eliminar un número de la lista.
        case 3:
        {
            int n; //Crear un varible que almacene el número a borrar de la lista.
            system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
            cout << "Ingrese el numero para borrar de la lista:" << endl; //Pedir por pantalla un nuúmero para borrar de la lista.
            cin >> n; //Capturar el número a borrar de la lista.
            system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
            borrar(&milista,n); //LLamar a la función borrar.
            if(i==0)
                cout << "Elemento borrado de la lista. Pulse cualquier tecla para regresar" << endl;
            system("pause"); //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: De verdad que debes releer lo que es un [mcve]. ¿ Para que pones **todas** las funciones si el error de compilación te lo da en solo 1 ? ¿ Y el switch ? Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio :-(

Comment: @Trauma no sólo lleva tiempo en el sitio, además ha presentado el mismo código varias veces en tres años, no ha cambiado el código, no ha entendido las respuestas proporcionadas, no ha aprendido de sus preguntas y ha preguntado varias veces lo mismo de maneras diferentes.

Comment: No escondas los punteros con el keyword `typedef`, esto lo único que hace es confundir al lector. Por cierto, los errores de compilación son debido a que estás pasando en el primer parámetro un argumento de tipo `int`, cuando en realidad debería ser de tipo `Hash`.

Comment: Puse HashInsertar(&h,e);  dónde e es la clave del hash para el elemento, y ahora no tira error pero el programa sigue andando mal

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Supongo que has leído los comentarios de los de mas OP, te recomiendo realizar estos cambios. ademas solo debes realizar bien la conversión del tipo de dato de la variable o enviar la variable con el tipo de dato que es, ese es el error que pusiste.

Answer (score 3):

El error es simple, claro, conciso, explícito, inequívoco y acotado. Entiendo que tal vez no comprendas el inglés, por eso te traduciré el error… lo que no entiendo es que hayas presentado el código cinco veces en cinco preguntas distintas y no hayas aplicado ni una sola vez ninguna de las mejoras, consejos o cambios que se te han propuesto.

- Septiembre de 2017

  - [Lectura de datos tipo NodoL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102140/2742).
  - [warning: passing argument 1 of 'enlistar' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102801/2742).
- Agosto 2018

  - [warning: passing argument 1 of 'HashInsertar' from incompatible pointer type](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/192263/2742).
- Agosto 2019

  - [Advertencia con listas en c “warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/287614/2742).
- Febrero 2020.

  - [Programa de Hash en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/329990/2742).

Estos son los errores en español:

> error: conversión inválida de 'int' a 'nodoL**'

> error: inicializando argumento 1 de 'void HashInsertar(nodoL**, int)'

Y te está diciendo que estás llamando a la función `HashInsertar` pasando un entero (`int`) donde deberías estar pasando un `nodoL**`, que es el primer argumento de dicha función.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no me están respondiendo a lo que me están preguntando. Como solución me ponen un código quizás equivalente pero distinto al que estoy posteando. Sus soluciones las voy a implementar y tieran error y no corrigen el problema. Yo quiero mantener el código lo más parecido posible y no hacer cambios drásticos en el. Sus respuestas no me sirven.

Comment: Falso. Al menos en esta pregunta te he respondido exactamente a lo que preguntas: ¿Qué puedes hacer para resolver el error? Pasar un `nodoL**` como primer parámetro.

Comment: Por otro lado, tu código tiene serios problemas de diseño y denota serios problemas de comprensión del lenguaje, si te aconsejamos cambiarlo es porque de no hacerlo tendrás problemas en el futuro y si te damos consejos de programación es para que mejores tu nivel.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro te proponen un código diferente porque, bien es mejor, bien el tuyo directamente no funciona... ¿no te has parado a pensar que quien te responde sabe más que tu sobre este tema y que tal vez deberías hacerle caso y entender lo que te cuentan?